# iOS app Continuous Integration with Hudson: use -workspace and -scheme, or -project?

Tags: ios, hudson, three20, xcodebuild

I'm trying to get a Hudson CI build set up for our iPhone app effort.  We are using the Three20 UI frameworks to build the app.  So far I can't make the build work if I use xcodebuild -project.  The -workspace option seems to work better, once I make the schemes shared.  Is this the way most teams work?

Comment: what happens when you build using `-project`?

if you want it built according to a scheme you have set up then you will indeed need to make sure the scheme is shared. if you don't do this, then the scheme will only be available on your mac.

Comment: @MikeK - When I build with `-project` it does not find all of the files from Three20.  I get a few compile errors saying `Three20/Three20.h does not exist`. Does `-project` work effectively for building multi-framework apps?

Comment: hmm, that's interesting. as far as i know, it should work. i've never used `-workspace`, but now i think about it i probably setup the include paths by hand. `-workspace` and `-scheme` are probably a more Xcode4 way to do things. you should only need to share one scheme for use on the build machine.

Comment: Follow-up: -workspace seems more reliable in tying together this bunch of projects.  We've been sticking with it, seems to be best.